# Error al ejecutar aplicacion WPF en otro equipo

Tags: .net, wpf

Buen día, terminé mi proyecto, es una aplicación de escritorio (WPF) pero necesito distribuirlo por lo cual copio la carpeta debug en el equipo cliente pero no ejecuta, reviso el task manager y solo sale esto lo que aparece en la imagen, posterior a esto el proceso desaparece.

La versión de .net framework es la misma que tengo el equipo en el cual fue desarrollada, utilizo archivos que están dentro de debug por lo que si el problema fuera que no encuentra el archivo al menos iniciaría la aplicación. Espero pueda ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Ticket.classes;
    using BarcodeLib;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using Microsoft.Office.Core;
    using System.IO;`

```
namespace Ticket
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
        private DataSet Search;
        private conex conectar = new classes.conex();
        private TicketTurno turno = new classes.TicketTurno();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("/Resources/image.png");
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;

    private string code;
    private FunctionsMicrosoft fntMicro;
    private Excel._Workbook oBook;
    private Excel._Application oExcel;
    private Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    public int rows;
    public Excel.Range range;
    public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        fntMicro = new FunctionsMicrosoft();
        oExcel = new Excel.Application
        {
            Visible = false

        };
        code = Barra(Convert.ToString(rfc.Text));
        object printer = oExcel.ActivePrinter.StartsWith(@"RICOH SP 5300");
        //abriendo archivo para la impresion del ticket
        //oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:/RHSystem/TickeSTurno.xlsx.", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"/TickesTurno.xlsx", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets[1];

        MessageBox.Show(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/TickesTurno.xlsx");

        Search = conectar.fillTable("insert into [RHInterview] ([Name],[RFC],[FirstLastname],[SecondLastname],[Date]) values ('" + nombre.Text + "','" + rfc.Text + "','" + paterno.Text + "','" + materno.Text + "',getdate())");

        oSheet.Range["A5"].Value = nombre.Text;
        oSheet.Range["B7"].Value = paterno.Text;
        oSheet.Range["B9"].Value = materno.Text;
        oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + code + "", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 1, 190, 140, 20);
        oSheet.Range["A6"].Value = "Turno: "+Convert.ToString(contador());
        oBook.RefreshAll();
        oExcel.Calculate();
        oBook.Save();
        oBook.Close(true);
        oExcel.Quit();
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"/TickesTurno.xlsx", missing, false, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing);
        oBook.PrintOut(1, 1, missing, missing, printer, missing, missing, missing);
        oExcel.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
        nombre.Clear();
        paterno.Clear();
        materno.Clear();
        rfc.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(code);
        if (File.Exists(code))
        {
            File.Delete(code);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }

        }
    public int contador() {
        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        int i = 0;
        int turno;
        Search = conectar.fillTable("select * from rhInterview where Date = '"+dt+"' order by idInterview desc");
        i = Convert.ToInt32( Search.Tables["Table"].Rows[0][0].ToString());
        turno = i;
        return turno;
        }
    public Bitmap Resize(Bitmap bmp,int width,int height) {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width,height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
        g.DrawImage(bmp,0,0,width,height);
        return result;
        }

    public string Barra(string rfc) {

        BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode(rfc);
        b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, rfc, System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White, 290, 120);
        string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
         string file = rfc+".jpg";
        string fullpath = path + file;
        b.SaveImage(fullpath, SaveTypes.JPG);
        return fullpath;
    }

    private void txtletras_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

        int ascci = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(e.Text));
        if (ascci >= 65 && ascci <= 90 || ascci >= 97 && ascci <= 122)
            e.Handled = false;
        else

            e.Handled = true;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Primero no deberias copiar la carpeta debug, si no la release (se va a ejecutar mas rapido tu programa). Segundo, con la informacion que das es imposible saber que pasa.. que hace tu programa? en que parte se traba? llega a mostrar algo? agregaste alguna especie de log para ver donde se clava? asi como esta, no vamos a poder responderte nada.

Comment: mi programa imprime tickets de turno, sobre si muestra algo la respuesta es no, en ningun momento abre una ventana.

Comment: Necesitas crear un instalador para asegurarte que te llevas todas las referencias y requerimientos de instalacion, que version de VS y framework estas usando, revisa [crear instalador wpf](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application/)

Comment: Y esos equipos tienen instalada la versión de .NET Framework que tu usaste?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, cuando una aplicación falla sin dar ninguna explicación, lo más posible es que falte alguna de las referencias necesarias.

Veo que en tus `using` importas `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` y `Microsoft.Office.Core` que posiblemente estén en tu sistema porque se hayan instalado con Visual Studio o con algunos de los plugins de Office pero no tienen porqué estar en el ordenador del usuario.

Una forma de comprobarlo es crear una aplicación sin ninguna referencia, instalar en el equipo destino para ver si funciona e ir probando a añadirlas una a una hasta que encuentres el error.